# How can i add bootstrap popover to w2grid custom button?

Tags: javascript, w2ui

How can I implement a bootstrap popover on the custom button in the w2ui grid?

Answer (score 0):

You dont have any code samples or extracts. So the simple answer would be to add the data-attributes dynamically with js then create an instance with the Bootstrap popover JS.

[https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/popovers/#getorcreateinstance][1]

Again your question doesnt state wether the button is in a row or outside the grid, does it have a unique identifier?

Please elaborate more in order to get help. Also state what you have tried and what not.